# SFML Error - isOpen non-standard syntax;

Tags: c++, syntax, sfml

So I am getting this error: `game.cpp(15): error C3867: 'sf::Window::isOpen': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member`

Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

Game::Game() :
    window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!"),
    player() 
{ 
    player.setRadius(40.f);
    player.setPosition(100.f, 100.f);
    player.setFillColor(sf::Color::Cyan);
}

void Game::run() {
    while (window.isOpen) {
        processEvents();
        update();
        render();
    }
}

void Game::processEvents()
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }
}

void Game::update() {

}

void Game::render() {
    window.clear();
    window.draw(player);
    window.display();
}
```

And this is my game.h

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

class Game {
public:                         
    Game();        
    void run();
    sf::RenderWindow window;
    sf::CircleShape  player;
private:        
    void processEvents();        
    void update();        
    void render();
};
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, I looked trough other stackoverflow answers to the same error but they are all general and they do not help me fix this error because its from the SFML library. If someone know how to fix it please help me :)

Comment: Change `while (window.isOpen)` to `while (window.isOpen())`

Comment: You gotta be kidding me... did I seriously overlook that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `while (window.isOpen)` you are testing that the member function pointer 'window.isOpen' is not `nullptr`. What you intended was to *call* the function `while (window.isOpen())`.